# exclude directory from deployment (like tests)

Tags: meteor

i want to have a directory that is not deployed to the server, nor is it packaged to be sent to the clients.
I read the 'tests' dir behaves this way, but i don't want to store all my files that don't nee deployment in the tests dir. tests is just for tests...

I want to include my sass files (.scss) in my project, but only the compiled css needs to be deployed (I compile to client/style.css). All of the sass source files and compass configuration files don't need to be deployed anywhere.

How to do this?
I hope I don't need to stor everything in the tests dir...

Thanks!
Pieter

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423430/ignoring-files-in-a-meteor-js-project-directory), directories whose name start with a dot (Unix hidden directories) aren't included by meteor. I use it for my less partials: `client/css/.partials/_<partial_name>.less`.

Comment: As a complement, since dotted dirs aren't recognised by Meteor, auto-refresh doesn't apply to them. If you use that method with Sass files, you'll need to manually restart Meteor each time you change something in a dotted dir's partial.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify Meteor's app/lib/bundler.js, line 37 to include your extension:

```
var ignore_files = [
    /~$/, /^\.#/, /^#.*#$/,
    /^\.DS_Store$/, /^ehthumbs\.db$/, /^Icon.$/, /^Thumbs\.db$/,
    /^\.meteor$/, /* avoids scanning N^2 files when bundling all packages */
    /^\.git$/, /* often has too many files to watch */
    /*.scss$/
];
```

or you could make package.js for your sass files, using [stylus](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/stylus/package.js) as an example.