# Prevent Meteor from including files?

Tags: meteor

I know that Meteor doesn't include files in the `tests/` directory or `.*` directories. I would like it to also not include files in the `cron/` and `node_modules/` directories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring files in a Meteor JS project directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423430/ignoring-files-in-a-meteor-js-project-directory)

Comment: One of the directories that can't be included is node_modules (the cron tasks use node libs), and I can't add a `.` to that, so I'm looking for a more general-purpose configuration option.

Comment: Could you move your `cron/` and `node_modules/` directories into a parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such configuration option at this moment. Which folders are loaded is decided in [these lines](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/0.7.1.2/tools/packages.js#L1764-L1771) in Meteor source:

```
    // Read top-level subdirectories. Ignore subdirectories that have
    // special handling.
    var sourceDirectories = readAndWatchDirectory('', {
      include: [/\/$/],
      exclude: [/^packages\/$/, /^programs\/$/, /^tests\/$/,
                /^public\/$/, /^private\/$/,
                otherSliceRegExp].concat(sourceExclude)
    });
```

To skip other folder, you'd have to fork Meteor and tweak those lines.

Comment: Note: `otherSliceRegExp` excludes either `client` or `server` directory.