# Stop meteor live reload for particular folder

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any hack or other method to set ignore list of folders for Meteor's hot reload.
For example I want to prevent page reloading, when I changing files in **public** folder

Comment: I think this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10423608/3225

Comment: I created ".test" folder and file there and it do not work

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504883/how-to-prevent-meteor-from-watching-files/25161820#25161820

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".#Name_of_folder".
Meteor ignores any directories that begin with a ".#"