# Include a non-core package within a meteor project

Tags: meteor

I can add a package to a custom checkout of meteor as outlined in [How to build a Meteor smart package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114526/how-to-build-a-meteor-package)

But this doesn't really work when developing with others.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it within a project? A-la the old Rails `vendor/plugins`? If not, perhaps it could be something the devs might want to implement..

Comment: What do you mean with `But this doesn't really work when developing with others.`? I'll try to post an answer but am not 100% if I understood your question right...

Comment: What I mean is that I want people to be able to just clone my repo and run `meteor` and have my app running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need others to use your package but you don't want your package in Meteor, then you could just fork the Meteor repo and work on your fork instead of Meteor itself. That way, the others can clone your repo instead of Meteor...

Comment: Yeah it works, but it is a bit involved (two pulls every time, remembering to run a local meteor). It'd be much simpler to have a `/vendor/packages` directory in my app and to throw packages in there. At least until there is a gem/npm style system for meteor packages...

Comment: Secondly, things are going to get hairy once you start running multiple projects with multiple (different versions?) of custom packages, with multiple distinct development teams..

Comment: @TomColeman: They've invented [submodules and subrepos](http://help.github.com/submodules/) for that. So it's just a matter of setting a single alias in your terminal and using that alias for whatever project in whatever development team you are in.